# Retag questions using [transition]

Tags: discussion, tags

There are 10 posts (as of this writing) using [transition](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transition). About half are about musical transitions (modulations or between sections of a piece), and about half are on a transition of skills (e.g., switching instruments).

The composition-related posts could appropriately be retagged with [modulation](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modulation) or [composition](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/composition). Perhaps there's value in [transition](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transition) regarding "transitioning" from one instrument to another, but I see two problems:

1. Answers are inherently opinion-based;
2. There's a rule of thumb that tags should represent an area of expertise, and "transitions", while perhaps a useful category, does not pass the area-of-expertise test.

#### Proposal

1. Retag the musical-transition-based questions to use [modulation](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modulation), [composition](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/composition), or other applicable tag.
2. Remove [transition](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transition) fron the remaining posts.
3. Update the [transition](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transition) wiki to say "Don't use this tag."

Comment: I think this one makes sense, but hoping for a few more of the regulars to vote or weigh in with thoughts

Comment: I’m all for this proposal, except you won’t need step 3; empty tags are removed automatically after some time.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that in all cases there are probably more specific words than "transition." Even the cases that aren't about musical architecture could probably use something else. E.g. there could be valid questions on switching from violin to viola, or on making musical contacts in a new city, or on switching from an amateur to professional basis. There could definitely be some about the "transition" from chest voice to head voice (and I suppose there could even be questions about the vocal impact of medical gender transition). But all these could be better served by more specific terms.